# Ok google распознавание речи

Tags: android, android-studio, распознавание-речи

Есть ли открытый код, который бы в постоянном реальном времени прослушивал OK google, для дальнейшей работы.
Например говорю Ok google (или другую фразу), включается распознавание речи, google сервер распознаёт нужный текст ---> идёт команда на открывание двери или включение света, через bluetooth-arduino.
Делаю проект помогающий упростить жизнь парализованному человеку до головы. Возможно этот проект поможет 1000 инвалидам.

Answer (score 2):

Уже сейчас вы можете встроиться в Assistant и сделать Actions - которые будут вызывать серверные события через функции Firebase https://developers.google.com/actions/

Вроде уже есть API для Android, но про реальный опыт пока не слышал https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/

Вот видео IO/18 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lu3L6DxUBRA

Если у вас действительно крутой проект напишите комуто из российский GDE - https://developers.google.com/experts/ обязательно помогут вам с ранним доступом.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview#custom

Comment: круто, пробовал серверные actions, надо будет проверить

Comment: Google Assistant API включил, добавил SHA1 и пакет. У меня большой опыт в ардуино, но с google серверами столкнулся впервые.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/?hl=ru

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidthings-assistant/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#2

Comment: я не могу понять почему они не используют андройд устройство + bluetooth + arduino. Это дешевле и проще.